# Typescript compile on build not working

Tags: asp.net, typescript, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I have VS2015 and ASP.NET 5 RC1 project with some typescript files. Files are located in scripts folder and tsconfig is in this folder too. When I'm saving typescript file, js file is generated and everything is ok. But js files are not generated during build.

I have VS2013 installed also and some old projects using typescript, so may be there are some problems cause I have many TypeScript versions and many VS versions.

How can I troubleshoot compiling typescript during build? Build log says nothing about typescript. Checkbox 'Compile TypeScript on build' is project settings is enabled. In old ASP.NET projects TypeScript is enabled via custom target in csproj and it's easy to troubleshoot. But in xproj I don't see any typescript related things.

Comment: Do you have a target import to Microsoft.Typescript.targets ?

Comment: @mohamedhegazy Nope, only import of Microsoft.DNX.Props and Microsoft.DNX.targets

Comment: can you share the build log with `/verbosity:diagnostic`

Comment: @mohamedhegazy Here is 2Mb log of msbuild: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2pS8f3oahxBd29wLTBRY1ZBbVk/view

Answer (score 2):

My current working solution is to add postbuild event which manually calls TypeScript compiler.

project.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "postbuild": ["tsc -p scripts\\tsconfig.json"]
}
```

(assumes you have tsc in your PATH variable)

Answer (score 0):

make sure  this is added in your solution file
"Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')"

Comment: Do you mean the project file, not the solution file? I have not got this line in xproj file, but adding it changes nothing. Does ASP.NET 5 need this import? I thought only older versions of ASP.NET needs it.

Comment: The sln file. These are built in extension for VS-15, but make sure these are not modified.

To edit sln file - Go to solution explorer-> unload project ->edit ->reload

Comment: There are only links to projects in sln. Where should I add import? http://pastebin.com/ZBg1TdEA

Comment: You can add just below the project tag

Comment: Changing my import to this does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Worked for me when I edited tsconfig, and placed compileOnSave BEFORE compilerOptions in *tsconfig*:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true
    "compilerOptions": {
         ....
    },
}
```